# How to test the touch screen like this progmatically

Tags: android, touch, screen, gesture

this is image

[image: 1]

I want to create an app to test the touch screen as shown in the above image.

so i need guideline to create this is there any github link ?

Comment: ok, good luck then!

Comment: @snachmsm i need guideline how to create thgis

Comment: show what you have created so far, where is the exact CODING problem. lack of knowledge isn't a problem desired to be resolved on SO, asking for whole working code or links is forbidden

Comment: Did you found a way

Comment: @YasiruNayanajith still no did you found?"

Answer (score 0):

You cant test your touch screen using program.

Touch screen can be tested only touching your screen. App just sending request to OS to press point on the screen.

Comment: i need how to create this !!! pragmatically

Comment: It is impossible. Reread my answer.

Comment: why this is impossible and is there any way to test your mobile which we are create pragmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586594/how-to-test-the-touch-screen-like-this

Comment: Program can't touch your screen. It can only send request to emulate screen touch. But it isn't a real touch